# Is there a functionality in mysql to order by to specific row?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a table e.g students:

```
 id | name
 -- |-----
 1  | A
 2  | B
 3  | C
 4  | D
 5  | E
 6  | F
 7  | G
 8  | H`
```

How to wite a sql in mysql so that  first 4 students are order by id ascending and rest order by id descending output should be something like this

```
id |  name
---|------
1  | A
2  | B
3  | C
4  | D
8  | H
7  | G
6  | F
5  | E
```

Comment: Yes you can use `case` statement in order by clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using are version of MySQL earlier than 8+, which means that you can't use analytic functions here.  Here is one way of doing this, using a correlated subquery with a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.id <= t1.id) <= 4
         THEN 0
         ELSE 1 END,
    CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.id <= t1.id) <= 4
         THEN id
         ELSE -id END;
```

[image]

### Demo

The reason I am calculating the row number above with a correlated subquery, rather than just using the `id`, is that perhaps your `id` values may not always start at `1`, or even be contiguous.  Row number always can correctly target the first row records, as *ordered* by the `id`, while the `id` value itself may not always suffice.

Note that analytic functions make the code a lot easier to read here.  Here is what you can do with MySQL 8+:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) <= 4 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) <= 4 THEN id ELSE -id END;
```

Comment: I strongly discourage the first approach.  Using a correlated subquery to enumerate the rows is very expensive.  If you are using MySQL 8+, then `row_number()` is a very good solution.

Comment: @GordonLinoff And I agree with you.  If the OP has such requirements long term, then upgrading/switching to a database which supports the basic analytic functions might be in order.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated sub query to calculate the "rank" of the row. Sorting is trivial:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t AS x WHERE id < t.id) AS rn
FROM t
ORDER BY CASE WHEN rn >= 4 THEN -rn END, rn
```

- `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t AS x WHERE id < t.id` assigns consecutive numbers to each row starting from 0
- `CASE WHEN rn >= 4 THEN -rn END` assigns NULL to rank number 0 ... 3 so secondary sort is required.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample data, the simplest method would be:

```
order by (case when id <= 4 then 1 else 2 end),
         (case when id <= 4 then id end),
         name desc;
```

If you don't know where the fourth id is, then:

```
select s.*
from students s cross join
     (select s2.id
      from students s2
      order by s2.id
      limit 3, 1
     ) as s4
order by (case when s.id <= s4.id then 1 else 2 end),
         (case when s.id <= s4.id then s.id end),
         s.name desc;
```